# Fetch the attributes using PHP crawler

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am trying to fetch the name,address and location from crawling of a website . Its a single page and dont want any other thing other than this. I am using the below code.

```
<?php

include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = "http://www.phunwa.com/phone/0191/2604233";
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="address-tags"]')->item(0);
for($i=0; $i < $div->length; $i++ )
    {

        print "nodename=".$div->item( $i )->nodeName;
        print "\t";
         print "nodevalue : ".$div->item( $i )->nodeValue;
         print "\r\n";
            echo $link->getElementsByTagName("<p>");
    }
?>
```

The website html source code is

```
 <div class="address-tags">
            <p><strong>Name:</strong> RAJ GOPAL SINGH</p>
            <p><strong>Address:</strong> R/O BARNAI NETARKOTHIAN, P.O.MUTHI TEH.&amp; DISTT.JAMMU,X, 181206</p>
            <p><strong>Location:</strong> JAMMU, Jammu &amp; Kashmir, India</p>
            <p><strong>Other Numbers:</strong> <a href="/phone/191/2604233">01912604233</a> | <a href="/phone/191/2604233">+911912604233</a> | <a href="/phone/191/2604233">+91-191-2604233</a></p>
```

Can somone please help me get the three attributes as output. Nothing is echop on the page as of now.

Thanks alot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `$dom->load($html);` instead of `$dom->loadHtml($html);`. After doing this you wil; find your html is not well formed, so `$xpath` stay empty.

Maybe try something like:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.phunwa.com/phone/0191/2604233');

$name = preg_replace('/(.*)(<p><strong>Name:<\/strong> )([^<]+)(<\/p>)(.*)/mis','$3',$html);
$address = preg_replace('/(.*)(<p><strong>Address:<\/strong> )([^<]+)(<\/p>)(.*)/mis','$3',$html);
$location = preg_replace('/(.*)(<p><strong>Location:<\/strong> )([^<]+)(<\/p>)(.*)/mis','$3',$html);
$othernumbers = preg_replace('/(.*)(<p><strong>Other Numbers:<\/strong> )(.*)/mis','$3',$html);
list($othernumbers,$trash)= preg_split('/<\/p>/mis',$othernumbers,0);
echo 'name: '.$name.'<br>address: '.$address.'<br>location: '.$location.'<br>other numbers: '.$othernumbers;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following for your XPath query:

```
//*[@class='address-tags']/p
```

so you're retrieving the actual paragraph nodes that are children of the 'address-tags' parent. Then you can use a loop on them:

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@class="address-tags"]/p');
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
   echo $nodes->item($i)->nodeValue;
} 
// or just
foreach($nodes as $node) {
   echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

Right now your code is properly fetching the first div that's found, but then you continue treating that div as if it was a DOMNodeList returned from an xpath query, which is incorrect. `->item()` returns a DOMNode object, which does NOT have an `->item()` method.

Comment: will this node work for HTML tag also . I am still not getting any output on this . Pease help